# Django: Creating a custom Slug

Tags: python, django

This is how I'm adding a slug in my django app,

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def _get_unique_slug(self):
        slug = slugify(self.question_text)
        unique_slug = slug
        num = 1
        while Question.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, num)
            num += 1

        if unique_slug == '':
        # then simply add an existing number to unique_slug

        return unique_slug

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self._get_unique_slug()
        return super(Question, self).save()
```

Problem is that in case slug is `''` then I want to auto add the number 1,2,3...n

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your function to something like:

```
def _get_unique_slug(self):
    unique_slug = slug = slugify(self.question_text)
    empty = False if unique_slug else True
    unique_slug = unique_slug or '1'
    for x in itertools.count(1):
        if not Question.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            break
        unique_slug = '{}'.format(x) if empty else '{}-{}'.format(slug, x)
```

Here you increment the count and check in the database until you find free slug that is unique.

Comment: Sir, it's not working if user asks the same question again. It's raising an error `slug already exists`.

Comment: Yeah, it's working fine in case there's a slug. But, if user types something like `???` then `slug = ' '`, what can we do in that condition Sir? Is there a way to stop user from saving the question or redirecting back to same page without saving the form?

Comment: Sir, its raising an error, `null value in column "slug" violates not-null constraint`. What should I do?

Comment: Sir, is there a way we can assign the `id` of Question as slug or we can redirect user without saving the form if `slug = ' '` ?

Comment: I don't understand how you get `null value` error since this function always returns unique slug.